# How to enable WebView for a Cordova Mobile App?

Tags: java, cordova, android-webview, hybrid-mobile-app

When I get context handles from code, I only see "Native". How do I enable WebView for a Cordova Mobile App (Hybrid). Is there a setting in project files that enables the WebView ? Please advise.

Unable to find a setting that sets the WebView = true

I am trying to get context handles for this Hybrid Mobile App ( Cordova ) and I see only native. I need to be able to get WebView to interact with the mobile elements for UI testing using Appium.

Comment: From the documentation, I can see that the method setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled is accountable for debugging web contents and is default set to false. How do I set this to true for a Cordova Mobile App (hybrid) project ?

Comment: Further More: In my case, It is necessary to set to true the setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled property on the android.webkit.WebView element. How can I set this ?

Comment: Source: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/